# compare shape of density plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to compare denisty plot shapes to each other. i already made just a general density plot but because they have different values I cant really compare their shape. I want them all overlayed exactly on top of each other.

this is my code now:

```
for descriptor in descriptors:
            plt.figure()
            descript = [descriptor]+ [descriptor+ '_'+ sets[i] for i in range(1,len(sets))]
            sns.kdeplot(data=df[descript], legend=False)
            plt.legend(labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc="center left")
            plt.title(descriptor.replace('_', ' ').capitalize())
            plt.xlabel(descriptor.replace('_', ' ').capitalize())
            plt.savefig('distribution_'+descriptor+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
            plt.close()
```

which results in the plot below.[image]

so how do I get all 5 of them on top of each other.

Comment: please provide a reproducible dataset

Comment: And answer this question: what do you define as them being on top of each other? Is it when their right-most points are at the same x-value? Left-most points? Their peaks? Centers of mass? There are many ways you can "line them up."

Answer (score 1):

The two comments there are very valid. So, my assumptions are:

1. By overlapping you are referring to the max value to be on top of
   each other.
2. As there is no data, I am using IRIS data

To do what you are looking for...

- Get the x-value for each of the curves where y is max. I have just plotted it as it was simpler for me. If there is another way, others can comment/update
- You plot the plots by shifting each curve by the value of max. This will move each curve on top of each other and the max will be a x=0

Note that this will show the plots together, but the x-values will obviously be different.

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
maxes=[]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in cols:
    x, y = sns.kdeplot(iris[col], ax=ax).get_lines()[-1].get_data() # Get the x and y values
    maxid = np.argmax(y) # The id of the peak (maximum of y data)
    maxes.append(x[maxid]) # Append the x value which has max-y to maxes list

plt.cla() ## Clear and start plotting the shifted curves

## The actual plot
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    sns.kdeplot(iris[col]-maxes[i], ax=ax) # Plot with the shift, so that each curve is at 0
ax.axvline(ls=":", c='k')
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]